# Light easy way to implement contour drawing feature?

Tags: c++, image, drawing, line

I am trying to implement a feature of drawing closed contour that defines my region of interest. I would like to manually draw a contour that encloses some object in a image using my mouse. The contour should be closed at the end, something like ImageJ does. I am wondering if there is any tools, 3rd party libs in C++ can help with this. I know probably OpenCV can be a source, but I am trying to implement something light and easy. So is there anyway to do so? Any pointer is appreciated. Thanks. --Nick

Comment: Nah, there is no easier CV framework I am aware off compared to OpenCV.

Comment: So in order to use OpenCV contour drawing features, do I have to install the entire OpenCV package, or do I only a couple of dlls? If it is the later case, what OpenCV dll do I exactly need? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use WPF. An excellent example can be found here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128705/WPF-rounded-corners-polygon